# git not running in powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I was facing issue with git in powershell so I uninstalled it and reinstall using [this official post](https://www.develves.net/blogs/asd/articles/using-git-with-powershell-on-windows-10/)
 after installing when I open through shortcut as mentioned in post it worked. but if I open normal powershell I ran git command it is considering git as a file and asking me `how do you want to open it?` I am not understanding what happened there?

Comment: What are you typing in PowerShell to run git?

Comment: just `git` or to get version `git --version`

Comment: What's the output of `Get-Command git`? It should point to git.exe if the path environment variable is properly set.

Comment: output of command `CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     git                                                0.0.0.0    C:\WINDOWS\system32\git`

Comment: Seems you have an erroneous file in your system directory named `git`. Can't say it is safe to delete but you should investigate what it contains and then decide. Normal git installation doesn't put this file there so this is something else that just happens to be named `git`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you told us in the comments, `Get-Command git` returns:

```
CommandType Name Version Source
----------- ---- ------- ------
Application git  0.0.0.0 C:\WINDOWS\system32\git
```

Which shows, that your `system32` folder contains a file named `git` (without extensions). As `system32` is part of your `%PATH%`, typing `git` in your PowerShell, points to `%WINDIR%\system32\git`, and because it has no extension, Windows does not know, how to deal with it and asks you.

**Why does this happen?**

Usually this happens when one wants to pipe output from one command to another by using the wrong pipe operator in cmd, e.g. `someCommand > git`

To fix this, just remove `git` from system32 and ensure that your `%PATH%` (`$env:Path` in PowerShell) variable points to your git installation directory.

If not, **add your git installation to `%PATH%`**

- either **temporary** by typing `$env:Path += ";C:\path\to\git"`,
- or **permament**

  - using System settings (like already described in other answer)
  - Using PowerShell:
    `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\path\to\git", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)` (`Machine` can be replaced with `User`)

Comment: I'm really sorry for this comma mess; would love if someone could fix it

Comment: Also (temporary fix): if you have Git in your `system32` (and don't want to remove it) and installed Git via the installer, you might need to move `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` before `system32` in your path.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the git installation path to System environment variable PATH as follow
pres windows home button then type  **advanced system settings**

```
Environment Variable-->System variables-->path-->edit
```

add the the git installation path like this

```
;\git\path\bin
```

Then reboot your system, then try in powershell it should work

Comment: This worked for me by making the change then just restarting Powershell not the whole computer.